# What term would you use for a person who caused an incident

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

I am working on a procedure for my company and I am seeking a term to use for someone who causes an incident/accident.

Example: Have "term" fill out an incident report as soon as they are able to.

Comment: What's wrong with just ***the employee***? I'm assuming that the meaning will be understood in the context of the procedure, since the person would have been identified earlier anyway.

Comment: I wasn't sure if there was a single term or not, rather than the employee. I ended up going with FumbleFingers suggestion, but i am curious to see what other words appear.

Comment: "Culprit" is too judgmental.  Please don't use that.  Use "The employee" or "the relevant individual" or "the person implicated."

Comment: Have you considered that, if there are two (or more) people involved in the 'incident',  there may be a dispute / disagreement regarding who actually *caused* the incident?  Hence, if each of the two people involved think that it was the other person's fault, then neither person will complete the incident report because neither of them considers it to be have been caused by themself.  So maybe you should be asking for *everyone* involved in the incident to complete an incident report!

Comment: Your problem here is the use of the phrase "causes an incident". That suggests culpability on someone's part (unless it was a good or beneficial "incident"). However if it is still an "incident" and not something more specific, it would seem unlikely that at that point responsibility has been determined. So what exactly do you mean by "causes an incident"? Should you perhaps be talking about the person "reporting" an incident?

Comment: 'Party involved' or 'involved party'.

Comment: It really depends on whether the report comes before the investigation or afterwards. For example, a nurse who poisons a patient may have unkowingly administered a drug that came to her from a trusted source, such as a fellow nurse or a messenger from the hospital pharmacy. It is a very serious mistake to imply fault where none may be present. Even after an investigation, it is best to be non-judgemental in the reporting of the facts.

Answer (score 2):

A neutral term for this would be [**principal**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/principal#h2):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   *noun*
>   **1** : a person who has controlling authority or is in a leading position: such as
>   **e** : the person primarily or ultimately liable on a legal obligation

In other words:

> Who was the *principal* of the incident.

Admittedly, it's not an entirely common use of the word, but it's still acceptable.

---

It could also be used adjectivally, a form that would be more common:

> Who was *principally* involved in the incident?

This, too, uses neutral wording.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if the word 'principle' has or ever can be used in a derogatory sense.

Comment: @Lawrence Thank you for the note! It wasn't my link that was incorrect, it was my fingers having inadvertently typed *principle* in the body of my answer. I actually did it twice without spotting the error. I have fixed the text.